# Getting values from a TABLE using SELECT inside a TRIGGER (Oracle SQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am working on a Music Collection Database Project and I am stuck on this TRIGGER code. There is an Album table and the task of the trigger is to check if the album being entered already exists in the table or not. And if it does, it should copy the rating which is already present in the table for the album irrespective of the new one entered by the user. (I am using Oracle 11g)

The trigger I managed to get is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER album_constraints BEFORE INSERT ON Album
DECLARE
  a_id int;
  a_title varchar(50);
  a_duration varchar(6);
  a_number_of_tracks int;
  a_recorded date;
  a_rating int;
BEGIN
  SELECT album_id,
         album_title,
         album_duration,
         album_number_of_tracks,
         album_recorded,
         album_rating
  INTO a_id,
       a_title,
       a_duration,
       a_number_of_tracks,
       a_recorded,
       a_rating
  FROM Album
  WHERE album_title = new.album_title and
        album_duration = new.album_duration and
        album_number_of_tracks = new.album_number_of_tracks and
        album_recorded = new.album_recorded and
        rownum = 1;

  IF new.album_title = a_title and
     new.album_duration = a_duration and
     new.album_number_of_tracks = a_number_of_tracks and
     new.album_recorded = a_recorded
  THEN
    new.album_rating := a_rating;
  END IF;
END;
```

Can someone please help me achieve this? I am getting multiple errors such as "PL-SQL : Statement ignored"

Comment: Why did you add tag `sql-server`  and `mysql` to this question?

Comment: And why would you allow the same album to be inserted multiple times in the table to begin with?  Wouldn't it make more sense to have a constraint that prevented the duplicate row from being inserted to begin with?

Comment: Its one of the cases given to us. A person can have multiple albums, either CD or Vinyl, etc. It can also be a case if the old one is in poor condition and he bought another one.

Comment: @JubinSanghvi - Then your data model is wrong.  You'd want an `album` table that stores album level information like the rating and then a separate table to store information about the different copies of that album.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but we have been asked to use a single table and use triggers for the rating check.. I am completely new to triggers so could you help me with the trigger?

Comment: As Justin said, your data model is wrong. If you could write a trigger to hide the problem, you just allow the problem to fester without actually solving anything. Fortunately, you probably can't write such a trigger. A trigger on a table cannot just go out and read from the same table. The table is mutating (the code is actually inside the INSERT statement). Whoever is asking this of you is lazy and wants you to do a bunch of work just so they don't have to. Just tell them what the real problem is and that it can't be fixed by trigger. (It can, however, be fixed by a view.)

Comment: @TommCatt - what you say is correct **for row triggers**. If you look at the trigger code shown you'll see it does not include the `FOR EACH ROW` clause, and thus is a statement trigger rather than a row trigger.

Comment: @BobJarvis: I didn't notice the lack of the FOR EACH ROW clause, possibly because the body of the trigger contains code that makes sense only in a row-level trigger. However, that doesn't change my point. Using a trigger to hide a design flaw should be *strongly* opposed. You only make the design more fragile and needlessly complicate future maintenance efforts.

Comment: If you need to implement such logic, why do you not implement it in the original insert statement? Triggers are a terrible way to implement business logic.

Comment: Thanks @TommCatt, how can I achieve the rating check if I use another table for multiple albums?

Comment: I re-read your entire original question and I realize you don't mention users of your database. Is this a single-user application or will you have multiple users who will have their own rating for the same album?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to do what you are trying to do using a single table. It just doesn't involve triggers. Here's a code fragment showing the insert statement:

```
begin
    insert into Album( id, title, duration, number_of_tracks, recorded, rating )
    values( v_id, v_title, v_duration, v_number_of_tracks, v_recorded, v_rating );
exception
    when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
        update Album
            set rating = v_rating
        where  id = v_id;
end;
```

This assumes ID is the PK and it is something like an ISPN number which uniquely identifies each published album, not a sequential value. If the album does not exist in the table, the Insert statement executes normally. If the album already exists, the Insert statement fails, the exception is caught and the Update is executed instead.

If you really, really want to use a trigger, then front the table with a view and create an "instead of" trigger on the view. To avoid having to make any changes in the app code, name the view Album and the table something else. (My convention is to call the table "Album_". The trailing underscore tells me that no direct access to the table is allowed and there is a view without an underscore where all access takes place. You can use whatever convention you want, of course.)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER album_constraints
instead of INSERT ON Album
for each row
begin
    insert into Album_( id, title, duration, number_of_tracks, recorded, rating )
    values( :new.id, :new.title, :new.duration, :new.number_of_tracks, :new.recorded, :new.rating );
exception
    when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
        update Album_
            set rating = :new.rating
        where  id = :new.id;
end;
```

Here is where I have to give a hat tip to Sql Server. It allows "instead of" triggers on tables making a "pass thru" view unnecessary.